# Matlab: 2 non-continuous colorbars and colormaps in the same figure

Tags: matlab, axes, colorbar, colormap

I'm completely stranded!!!

Could anyone give me a hand with this issue? Thanks in advance.

1. What I wanted: I want to plot a brain network such that nodes have their own colormap (jet) and colorbar and, in the same figure, the links with their own colormap (gray) and colorbar.
2. Problem: When I display on screen the head with two colorbars from two different colormaps, both colorbars display with the first declared colormap (jet) in my code. In other words, it seems that the first declared colormap (jet) re-writes the last declared colormaps (gray). The figure displayed shows the first colormap (jet) and never shows an independent colorbar gray!!!
3. What have I done?: I had follow so many links through these forums and mathworks helps to build my own script. I'm naive in Matlab and I using it in macOS with matlab version R2013a. The code looks like this:

   ```
   Figure
   hold
   plot1 with data1 associated to colormap(gray)
   plot2 with data2 associated to colormap(jet)

   axis square
   axis off
   box off
   set(gca,'XTick',[],'YTick',[])
   set(gcf, 'units','normalized','outerposition',[0 0 1 1]) %EXPANDING FIGURE ON SCREEN

   ax1 = gca;   %GETTING THE AXES OF THE FORMER FIGURE
   ax1p = get(ax1,'Position');

   colormap(ax1,'jet')   %colorbar for nodes
   cb1 = colorbar('west');
   set(cb1, 'Position', [ax1p(1)+ax1p(3)-0.17  ax1p(2)+0.17  0.03          ax1p(2)+ax1p(3)-.3])
   set(cb1, 'fontsize', 30);
   caxis([min(n_atribut) max(n_atribut)]);

   ax2 = axes;        %getting axes for second colorbar
   set(ax2, 'Position', ax1p);     % Co-locate ax2 atop ax1
   ax2p = get(ax2, 'Position');
   axis off;                       % Make ax2 invisible 
   linkaxes([ax1,ax2],'xy');       % Link ax1 and ax2 so zooming will work properly: 

   colormap(ax2,'gray')  %colorbar for links
   cb2 = colorbar('west'); % Create a new colorbar
   set(cb2, 'Position', [ax2p(1)+ax2p(2)+0.6  ax2p(2)+0.17  0.03          ax2p(2)+ax2p(3)-.3])
   set(cb2, 'fontsize', 30);
   caxis([min(w_atribut) max(w_atribut)]);
   axes(ax2);
   hold off
   ```
4. Figures. The figure bellow shows the problem and it is what I get when I run my code
   [image]
   As you can see, even when both colorbars have their proper limits associated to data1 and data2, the second (the one to the extreme right) is plotted with colormap jet.
   This next figure shows what I looking for:
   [image]
   Obviously, this one was edited in other software to get the colormap gray of the second colorbar.

Having said so, Can anyone could help me please? If it is important I could send the complete code and the 4 files to run and get the wrong figure!
Thanks in advance guys I appreciate all your helps.
Gohann.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably looking for the [freezecolor](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7943-freezecolors---unfreezecolors/content/freezeColors/freezeColors.m) function.

Comment: Thanks Ratbert, your link was very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got my answer due to the comment of Ratbert and the works of so-many guys from Matlab® file exchange. Thankful for the scripts freezeColors.m and cbfreeze.m and double2rgb.m by John Inversen and David Legland Carlos Adrian vargas.
This how I resolved the problem.

```
% % % % NODOS
cm1 = colormap(jet);
cb1 = colorbar('Location', 'east', 'fontsize', 30);
caxis([min(n_atribut(n_atribut>0)) max(n_atribut)])
cbfreeze(cm1)
freezeColors(ax1)
% % % % LINKS
cm2 = colormap(bone);
cm2 = flipud(cm2);
colormap(cm2);
cb2 = colorbar('Location', 'west', 'fontsize', 30);
caxis([min(w_atribut) max(w_atribut)])
cbfreeze(cm2)
freezeColors
```

The function/toolKit Easy Plot EEG Brain Network is now available in GitHub and Matlab Fileexchange.
[Matlab@ FileExchange](http://es.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/57372-easy-plot-eeg-brain-network-matlab)
[GitHub Reposiroty](https://github.com/JohannHM/Easy-Plot-EEG-Brain-Network-Matlab)
Thanks to everyone.